# JS can't map over array created with new Array(100)

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

This doesn't work. `b` is just full of undefined.

```
const a = new Array(100);
b = a.map((c, idx) => idx);
console.log(b);
```

If I spread `a` into a new bracketed array, `b` contains the indices as expected:

```
const a = [...new Array(100)];
b = a.map((c, idx) => idx);
console.log(b);
```

What's going on here? Is there some difference in the arrays created with `[]` and `new Array()`?

As far as I know, `new Array(n)` is the only easy way to create an array with a number of elements.

Cheers.

Comment: _"new Array(n) is the only easy way to create an array with a number of elements"_ - No, it isn't. `new Array(n)` does nothing more than setting the `.length` property of the array: [`23.1.1.1 Array ( ...values )`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array) -> 5.e `Perform ! Set(array, "length", intLen, true)`

Comment: Both examples end up with `b` being an array of 100 empty slots? I assume if you want a quick array with the items being 1..N. Use `new Array(100).fill('').map((c, idx) => idx)`

Comment: @evolutionxbox `Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, i) => i)`

Comment: @Andreas that is magic!